# Load .xaml file and edit object tree at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, runtime, custom-controls

After reading into XamlWriter and XamlReader, I was wondering if it is possible to load an arbitrary .xaml file at runtime, edit the object tree and then reuse it again.

What I am trying to create is a kind of showcase application for all available styles of a project. I've got TemplateViews for several ControlTypes (such as ButtonTemplateView.xaml, ListboxTemplateView.xaml ...), with their `Style` property bound to a viewmodel, which get dynamically constructed for each fitting style at runtime and then added to the main view.
But I also want to show all styles for the CustomControls of the project, which right now I am doing via `Activator.CreatInstance` with the `TargetType`of the style, and then adding the object to the main view.

Now, lets say if a CustomControl *MyCustomTextBox* is based on a TextBox, can I just load the TextBoxTemplateView.xaml, switch every <**TextBox** ... /> to a <**MyCustomTextBox** .../> and then add it to my main view?
If so, how? Can I turn it into a string and just replace the words and then turn it back into something usable? Or do I have to edit the UserControl object I get when I use `XamlReader.Load`? Or something else?

I hope this is not a duplicate question (at least I didnt find anything like it) and thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: If I knew how, I would... Why do you think I came here?

Comment: "switch every <TextBox ... /> to a <MyCustomTextBox .../>" sounds like a simple string replacement before loading the XAML. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: No I havent, because I don't know where to start. Can I edit the file directly? Can I turn it into a string and just replace the words and then turn it back into something usable? Or do I have to edit the `UserControl` object I get when I use `XamlReader.Load`? Or something else?

Comment: See here for an example how to load XAML from string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Comment: Thanks, but I have read this page already and it doesnt answer my question. This will just return a UserControl Object, but then what do I do with it? To be clear, I want the properties of the new control to be the same, I just want to replace the ControlType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either replace all occurances of `<TextBox>` with `<local:MyCustomTextBox>` in the `string` that you pass to the `XamlReader.Load` method. This is probably the easiest way because then the `XamlReader` will create the `MyCustomTextBox` elements for you.

The other option would be to iterate through the `<TextBox>` elements in the `UserControl` that is returned from the `XamlReader.Load` method and replace these by `MyCustomTextBox` elements. How to do this depends on where the controls are located in the element tree of the `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried the first approach, the problem is, how can I turn the .xaml file into a string? I tried to do it with `GetManifestResourceStream`, but then I'd have to mark the file as embedded resource which makes it unusable. Is there a way to get a string out of my file and still use it in the project?

Comment: What's the build action of the file?

Comment: Page, it's a UserControl.

Comment: Then it is being compiled into BAML so there is no string to be found. If you set its Build Action to Output you can read the file as-is. The XamlReader class works with XAML, not BAML.

Comment: I dont have the option to set the Build Action to Output.
I there any other way to get the xaml string from the usercontrol?

Comment: Well, then I don't know why you are trying to parse the "file" because there is no file after the application has been built.

Comment: yeah thats why i asked if theres any other way to get the xaml as a string

Comment: Once again, there is no XAML at runtime. So the answer to that question is no.